# what does this mean ? : Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [f] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

My Code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.*;

 public class NewTest {

public WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void f(WebDriver driver) {


  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Cheitrav\\Desktop\\ISTQB\\chromedriver.exe"); 
  driver = new ChromeDriver();

  driver.get("http://www.guru99.com");


}
}
```

---

---

---

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Cheitrav\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--373686985\testng-customsuite.xml

[Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [f] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:244)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1293)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1020)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1110)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

FAILED: f
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [f] with [interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:244)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1293)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1020)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1110)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@5f2108b5: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@72d818d1: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@cb644e: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 3 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@5649fd9b: 4 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@4b4523f8: 24 ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods annotated with @Test cannot have parameters.  Try something like this:

```
public class NewTest {
    @Test
    public void f() {
       WebDriver driver;
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Cheitrav\\Desktop\\ISTQB\\chromedriver.exe"); 
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.get("http://www.guru99.com");
    }
}
```

There are problems with your code but my suggestion above should get you past the problem you asked about.

**Edit:** this answer was based on outdated information and is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I got the error because I had parameters in my test method, but I forgot to "map" the test method to its DataProvider.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike what @user246 said, it is possible to have parameters in `@Test` methods.

2 options exist:

- [Native injection](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection):

> Any @Before method or @Test method can declare a parameter of type
>   ITestContext.
>
> Any @AfterMethod method can declare a parameter of type
>   ITestResult, which will reflect the result of the test method that was
>   just run.
>
> Any @Before and @After methods can declare a parameter of
>   type XmlTest, which contain the current  tag.
>
> Any @BeforeMethod
>   (and @AfterMethod) can declare a parameter of type
>   java.lang.reflect.Method. This parameter will receive the test method
>   that will be called once this @BeforeMethod finishes (or after the
>   method as run for @AfterMethod).
>
> Any @BeforeMethod can declare a
>   parameter of type Object[]. This parameter will receive the list of
>   parameters that are about to be fed to the upcoming test method, which
>   could be either injected by TestNG, such as java.lang.reflect.Method
>   or come from a @DataProvider.
>
> Any @DataProvider can declare a
>   parameter of type ITestContext or java.lang.reflect.Method. The latter
>   parameter will receive the test method that is about to be invoked.

- [Parameters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters)

Comment: Can you complete your answer with an example of how to fix the Op's problem?

Comment: No, I can't. The objective behind the question is not clear enough and there are too many ways to do it. The accepted question is a good way to solve the issue and I've just pointed the wrong statement about parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code regarding Leetcode 359. Logger Rate Limiter

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Logger {
    Map<String, Integer> map ;
    public Logger() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public boolean shouldPrintMessage(int timestamp, String message) {
        // 1. if the message appears before
        //    1.1 it has been 10 seconds since we' ve seen it
        // 2. if the message never appears before
        if(map.containsKey(message)){
            int lastTimestamp = map.get(message);
            if(lastTimestamp + 10 <= timestamp){
                map.put(message, timestamp);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            map.put(message, timestamp);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

when I test the function with parameters

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestLogger {
    Logger logger = new Logger();

    @Test
    public void shouldPrintMessage_messageNeverAppears(int timestamp, String message){
        boolean result = logger.shouldPrintMessage(3, "foo");
        assertEquals(false, result);
    }

}
```

there is exception

```
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [shouldPrintMessage_messageNeverAppears] with [int, class java.lang.String].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:441)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParametersForMethod(Parameters.java:355)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:712)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:879)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:744)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:783)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

All I need to do is remove parameters on test function.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestLogger {
    Logger logger = new Logger();

    @Test
    public void shouldPrintMessage_messageNeverAppears(){
        boolean result = logger.shouldPrintMessage(3, "foo");
        assertEquals(true, result);
    }

}
```